# AngularJS Unit testing with Restangular - nested promises

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, restangular

I'm testing my directive which used Restangular for some API calls in the controller.

For functions with promises used by Restangular I'm mocking those functions and putting together with my main model, which looks like this:

```
    model = {
        comments: comments,

        one: function () {
            deferred = $q.defer();

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        post: function () {
            deferred = $q.defer();

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        remove: function () {
            deferred = $q.defer();

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
```

And so when executing a function which runs Restangular's function e.g.:

```
    $scope.model.post('comments', newComment).then(...);
```

Me myself deciding to reject or to resolve it:

```
    deferred.reject();
    $scope.$digest();
```

Everything works fine but not when the functions are nested, for example like here:

```
    $scope.model.one('comments', comment.id).remove().then(...);
```

In this case I'm getting an error that remove is not defined (though I defined it):

```
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.model.one('comments', comment.id).remove()')
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Whats the status of this? Can I help?

Comment: If you can. I just skipped tests with nested actions, so .one.remove or .one.getList for example don't how how to mock...

Answer (score 0):

Your function 'one' returns a promise and not the model itself. The function 'remove' on the model but not on the promise. You can chain promise using 'then', but you can not chain your model function.

This code:

```
$scope.model.one('comments', comment.id).remove().then(...);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var promise = $scope.model.one('comments', comment.id);
promise.remove(); // error: 'remove' is undefined!
```

Another problem with your code is that you define deferred objects, and return promises (which is good), but you never 'resolve' or 'reject' your promise by calling 'resolve' or 'reject' functions of the deferred objects.

Comment: I think OP would call the 'resolve' or 'reject' in each test case, not in the mock object itself.

Comment: What do you mean by OP?

Comment: "Original Poster", see: [What does OP mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513)

Comment: So how to add that remove function properly on my mock?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example through jsfiddle or plunkr? Thx

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know how to provide a unit testing on those services.